# Faster way to generate permutation

Tags: java, string, optimization, permutation, n-gram

I'm working on a program that calculates a hit-percentage between two strings (A and B). To get an accurate percentage I'm matching N-Grams with a list of strings that are permutations of String A.

Here's my code

```
public String[] generatePermutations( String name ){

    String[] perms = new String[ calcN(name.length()) ];
    int nameLen = name.length(),
                cnt = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++ ){

        nameLen = name.length()-i;
        for( int ii = 0; ii <= i; ii++){
            perms[cnt++] = name.substring( ii, ii + nameLen );
        }
    }
    return perms;
}
```

for reference calcN() is below

```
public int calcN( int n ){
    return ( n * (n+1 )) / 2;
}
```

Given a String "ABC" this method will generate

> { "A", "B", "C", "AB", "BC", "ABC" }

Since I'm doing this operation thousands of times (perhaps hundreds of thousands) is there any way I can squeeze a few extra cycles out of my CPU? (besides switching to C++ or C). As always, thanks in advance for the advice!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code improvement rather than code fixing. Please visit [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) for this type of question.


Comment: It should be pointed out that substring is implemented differently in different jvms.  Some use the single invariant array that underlies the original string, others do a copy of the array into the new String.

Comment: is there any way to figure out which is which, or force the JVM to use one? I'm running Win7, 64 bit on a 3.5ghz i7-4770K

Comment: @Kyte `java -version` will tell you which one you are running (version and build).  If it doesn't say OpenJDK, it isn't OpenJDK. You can download the OpenJDK JVM from http://openjdk.java.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance optimization of the method depends in part on the JVM in use.  For example, in OpenJDK substring is implemented as:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
        new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

That string constructor is a protected form that is implemented as:

```
 // Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
     this.value = value;
     this.offset = offset;
     this.count = count;
 }
```

Note that this doesn't need to create a new value (the char[] that backs the String).

On the other hand, as described in [Java 7 Performance Tuning Guide](http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/) this was removed because of a memory leak (the single character substring of a 1000 character long string that gets garbage collected still retains the 1000 character string backing it).

And so, the choice of which jvm you are using could have a significant effect upon the creation of strings from substrings.

Depending on your application, and how critical that performance is, you might consider implementing your own limited version of the String that reimplements the offset and length implementation for substring.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. Performance shouldn't be an issue unless I decided to drastically scale up the size of the dataset, so efficiency on the permutation generator isn't _critical_. Thanks!

Comment: You can juggle which JVM you are using as described in [Changing JVM in Java](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107278/changing-jvm-in-java) for the appropriate environment you are on.  It could be an interesting test (for the sake of interesting) to see what the performance is like on different JVMs with a sufficiently large data set to show where things become different.

Answer (score 1):

I know, I am not probably helping but I couldn't resist.

Scala one-liner:

```
(1 to 3).flatMap("ABC".combinations(_))
```

returns

```
Vector(A, B, C, AB, AC, BC, ABC)
```

and

```
"ABC".permutations.toList
```

returns

```
List(ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA)
```

It is very easy to use Scala on top of JVM.

Comment: Note that 'AC' and 'BAC' are not part of the result set.  It appears that the desired set is described as "forward only, no skipping".  In essence, the strings with the index of: 1, 2, 3, 1-2, 2-3, 1-3.

Comment: Yeah, he said permutations, but gave example of something like "substrings only". I am not solving the problem I just wanted to demonstrate the power of Scala language.

Answer (score 0):

It would not help much, but I can not see the use of `cnt`, which simply use `ii`

Comment: edited code to remove the variable. That was leftover from a much earlier iteration of the method.

Comment: well I think your code is now wrong - of the same `perms[cnt]` will be updated multiple times.

Comment: edited code that explains the purpose of having the 'cnt' variable.

Comment: It looks like the same as it was.  When will `cnt` be any different to `ii`?

Comment: when ii = 1 and i is still assigned a 0 value. Note that there are three single character entries, two double char entries, and one triple char entry.